# ListView and AppBar cooperation. The simplest possible multiple select scenario

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, appbar

What is the SIMPLEST way of implementing list view multiple select scenario together with the AppBar? So that it behaves exactly as the Windows 8 start screen when multiple items selected (e.g. via the mouse right-click).

I want to show the app bar together with the first selected list view item, I want to keep it opened with the second, third and so on and I want to close it either by any app bar button action (context action performed) or by other system wide app bar close action (e.g. right-click somewhere else, which would mean context action cancelled).

My current implementation is too complicated. I believe I must have missed something - such a basic and common scenario must be possible to implement in a standardized way.

Scaffolding code prepared below. If only this code used the app bar hides before right-click on the second list view item and one more right-click on list view is required (not acceptable). If combined with IsSticky it is not possible to select the second list view item at all.

```
<Page
    x:Class="ListViewAndAppBar.ExamplePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ListViewAndAppBar"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding ExamplePageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <ListView
            x:Name="ListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
            SelectionMode="Multiple"
            SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar x:Name="BottomAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Button x:Name="BottomAppBarBack" Tag="Back" Style="{StaticResource BackAppBarButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </AppBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>

private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
    //this.BottomAppBar.IsSticky = true;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question. I found the solution short after I posted the question. I will leave it here in case somebody does the same beginner's mistake.

The solution cannot be simpler: **IsSticky must be called BEFORE IsOpen**. After this switch all works as expected.

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        this.BottomAppBar.IsSticky = true;
        this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = false;
        this.BottomAppBar.IsSticky = false;
    }

    // Or the following if you wish...
    // this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = this.BottomAppBar.IsSticky = this.ListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jan! I was just dealing with this same exact issue and changing the order of assignment of IsSticky=true and IsOpen=true fixed it for me too.